# If Else If Else - How can it work in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, if-statement

How does this  piece of code work?

```
 if name <> '' then 

    begin 
      sql_1
    end

else if PARAMETRIC then 
    begin
         sql2
    end 
else 
    begin
        sql3
   end
 end;
```

execute sql choosed by if or elseif or else.....

```
name = is a string
PARAMETRIC = is a boolean
sql1, sql2, sql3 are different queries (sorry for forgot it :( )
```

Comment: The first condition returns true if `name` isn't equal to '', while if it is the next condition will check your boolean variable/constant.

Comment: ok if name name condition is true, the second and third sql will be made or not?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: sorry for forgot it... but i'm out of mind with this new language for me that i must convert it into c# code (my best language i know!!).

Comment: @TLama thanks. Maybe it more clear. RBA said well. Warning....

Comment: What I was wondering was if the first statement is true, the other instructions will be executed? Or are you?

Comment: @CristianCapannini I you know C#, I really can't see where you'd be struggling with this. This translates to: `if (name <> '') then {sql_1;} else if (PARAMETRIC) then {sql2;} else {sql3;}` Perhaps it might help if you specifically state what you're unsure of?

Comment: First you should fix the horrible formatting.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no research and is unlikely to help further visitors of the site.

Comment: He is trying to learn, dont be so harsh. Apparently he is just starting out and thought comments / answers would help him more then reading about it in the delphi documentation. or he did not understand it..eitherway is no reason to put him down.

Comment: @Glen, there's a hot topic on meta these days. Overall StackOverflow quality is falling down. Questions like this (answer could be found in some basic tutorial) discourage people from contributing here. There's a lot of professionals leaving the community (or many of them just vote down and close questions). I feel the same and except my favorite Inno Setup tag I'm answering just in comments (it's bad I know, but on the other hand someone can get some votes for that :) For sure I can tell, StackOverflow is not a first steps learning site. [I'm not a downvoter]

Comment: @TLama I agree and see your point, but clearly you can tell this user is new. 1. Site is confusing its not always clear on what rules are where and for what site/ sister site. Its fine pointing out the rules and suggesting the question is closed or as you put its not a first step learning site. But being rude is just making other new users not want to come back. Thus the no input or comment is better then something rude/no help. That is the only point i am making and would like to see less of it.  cheers!

Comment: Also wanted to add... There is an If-Statement tag.. at what point is an if statement not a basic learning question.. so at somepoint someone who has been here awhile thought it should be a tag..

Comment: @Glen, from [`this point of view`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement?sort=votes) there seems to be a few useful questions. Also, there's a bunch of questions that exist just because they were asked a long time ago. And although I agree with you that at least one downvoter should explain what's wrong with the question, I don't see anything rude here.

Comment: Cause it was edited. A good thing. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short:

- If `name` is not empty, **only** `sql_1` will be executed
- If `name` is empty and `PARAMETRIC` is `true`, **only** `sql_2` will be executed
- If `name` is empty and `PARAMETRIC` is `false`, **only** `sql_3` will be executed

You can always add `begin`/`end` statements to make it look more obvious.

```
if name <> '' then 
    begin 
      sql_1
    end
else 
    begin
        if PARAMETRIC then 
            begin
                sql2
            end 
        else 
            begin
                sql3
            end;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You say (in comments) you know C#. Well, in Delphi it works exactly the same. You can write if .. else statements, and add an extra condition after the else.

In Delphi:

```
if condition1 then
begin // Open multi-line statement.
  Do1a;
  Do1b;
end
else if condition2 then
  Do2;
```

In C#:

```cs
if (condition1)
{ // Open multi-line statement.
  Do1a;
  Do1b;
}
else if (condition2)
  Do2;
```

So, while I don't really understand the confusion, the answer to your question is: No, they don't get all executed. If condition1 is true, the 'elses' won't be executed. If condition1 is false and condition2 is true, the second statement (do2) is executed. If both are false, nothing is executed (or in your case, the conditionless `else` is executed, so you get SQL3).